# Различные view в RecyclerView

Tags: android, recyclerview, recyclerview.adapter

Добрый день! Интересует следующее.
Подаю на адаптер `List<String> list`, который содержит в рандомном порядке текст и ссылки на картинки. Соответственно, мой `ViewHolder` содержит `TextView` и `ImageView`.
Я так понимаю, это неправильный подход. Нужно делать 2 `ViewHolder'a`, в один пихать `TextView`, в другой - `ImageView`.
Знаю, что в адаптере есть метод `getItemViewType()`. Но он подходил бы мне если бы я точно знал в какой позиции в моем списке идут текст и картинки. Но я этого не знаю, список рандомный. Как мне быть в моей ситуации?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Вы не знаете, но вы можете определить в какой позиции у вас ссылка а в какой просто текст. Например так:

```
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    if (list.get(position).contains("http")) {
        return TYPE_IMAGE;
    } else {
        return TYPE_TEXT;
    }
}
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо! Сам не понимаю, как не додумался до этого)